# Access Datacontext from binded user control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, user-controls

I have build a dynamic UserControl from an ObservableCollection as follows...

```
 public  static ObservableCollection<Model.Model.ControleData> ListControleMachine = new ObservableCollection<Model.Model.ControleData>();

     public Genkai(string Autorisation) {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                DataContext = this;
               
               icTodoList.ItemsSource = ListControleMachine;
               Model.Model.ControleData v = new Model.Model.ControleData();
               v.ComputerName = "M57095";
               v.ImportSource = "LOAD";
               ListControleMachine.Add(v);
    }
```

XAML

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="icTodoList" ItemsSource="{Binding ListControleMachine}" >
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ControlMachineII}">
         <local:ControlMachineII  />                                        
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But how can I access the DataContext from C# code?

For example say I want to delete the UserControl with a close button in itself, I need at least access ControleData.ComputerName value then remove it from Mainform.ListControleMachine.

I can't find the best practice for achieve this and play with my data in UserControl code.

The remove button code is like this i think (with hard coded value)

```
  Genkai.ListControleMachine.Remove(Genkai.ListControleMachine.Where(X => X.ComputerName == "M57095").Single());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finaly found that my DataContext was not yet initialized at start that why i got error so i had to wait for the datacontext first: here code for correction

```
     public ControlMachineII()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(ControlMachineII_DataContextChanged);


            }

   private void ControlMachineII_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string compname = (this.DataContext as Model.Model.ControleData).ComputerName;
            Console.WriteLine("DataContext initialized computername :" +compname);
        }
```

Comment: You know that for a very little problem(it was definitely Object reference error) you wrote a very big question definition. Also totally deviated from actual problem.

Comment: Very useful answer - thank you.  I had a hunch that the data context was not yet available when the component was initialized, but this showed me how to access it when it changed.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you posted same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550878/usercontrol-data-binding-retreive-value) today with some more data. I'm going to present the solution using that data.

**Solution 1 :**

***Use Tag property of button like below:***

```
<Button Content="Close this UC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="414,22,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" Click="Button_Click" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
```

***Event handler:***

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         var button = sender as Button;
         List<object> list = (button.Tag as ItemsControl).ItemsSource.OfType<TodoItem>().ToList<object>();
        list.Remove(button.DataContext);
        (button.Tag as ItemsControl).ItemsSource = list;
    }
```

**Solution 2:**

***More elegant solution:***

Create this `Style` in your `MainWindow`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Button_Click"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

> ***So now the Handler of any `Button` `Click` event in any `MainWindow's` descendant `Button` Control is in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs`.***

Then place the `handler` method in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` and change the `handler` like below:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        items.Remove(button.DataContext as TodoItem);
        icTodoList.ItemsSource = null;
        icTodoList.ItemsSource = items;            
    }
```

Comment: Microsoft force me add lot of code for a simple a task while this  line work well in button code Genkai.ListControleMachine.Remove(Genkai.ListControleMachine.Where(X => X.ComputerName == "M57095").Single());   but how i can get computername  value in my cs behind code it can't be that hard lol my UserControle don't even seem have a datacontext.gettype or anithing seting it via itemcontrol that turn me crazy.

Comment: i mean what if my controle need send a sql query with computername ? i have to got it from a label content?? i though i can retrieve simply my controledata object binded to the curent control it would be much better

Comment: @Zwan computername is a property of ControleData, which will be DataContext of item of ItemsControl. So in code behind you can get ControlMachineII.DataContext that will be a ControleData object. Am i getting your problem right? or it is something else?

Comment: but i'm  talk about usercontrol codebehind so it would be var MyData = this.dataContext as ControleData  then i get MyData.ComputerName  but this is not the way it work i don't get why???

Comment: and for your query question you can use "Ancestor Binding" or "ElementBinding" depending on the situation. WPF is designed to make things less coupled so that's why more coding, conversions & generic references.

Comment: @Zwan what are you talking about. this is exactly how it works in code behind of usercontrol. what do you mean "this is not the way it work"? "this is not the way it should work" or "this is not the way it is working"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104182/discussion-between-kylo-ren-and-zwan).

Comment: Ok i got it when this work in a UC button code  Console.WriteLine((this.DataContext as Model.Model.ControleData).ComputerName);   , this not working if i put it rigth under   InitializeComponent();  it's what put me in trouble cuz its where i want instantiate some variable using context if someone can tell why you are welcome it throw targetinvocation exception